# Best way to automatically generate highcharts image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, highcharts

I have some charts on my app and i need automatically generate images (e.g.: by day) to send through e-mail.

#### Environment

- ASP.NET MVC for website
- Highcharts
- Hosted on azure websites

I'm using highcharts and first choice was server export module, but using azure websites i can't setting up phantomjs on the server.

I also researched about "google chart images", but it's deprecated.

I am considering using the Chart (System.Web.Helpers) for it:

E.g.:

```
public ActionResult GetChartImage()
{
    var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
        .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
        .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Bubble",
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });

    return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
}
```

but was wondering if there is any more option to keep using of Highcharts.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I need to do (apart from Azure).  Did you ever find a solution for this using highcharts?

Comment: @dreza unfortunately not, currently this requirement is no longer necessary. If you need to use highcharts you will need a VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to generate charts on server for *Azure Web App* -> using ms-chart. 
You can generate highcharts on server only using *Azure VM*.

Comment: You're right, it's only possible to use highcharts export on a Azure VM today at least. Fortunately I don't need to do this any more. thank you.